# Copying and pasting from Macro workbook to multiple workbooks Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating a macro that will process and format scans (SCANfile#.xlm) saved as .xlm files  The end result should be a processed, formatted workbook that will be saved as an Excel file.  I am creating the macro in a workbook I will call SCANMacro for the purpose of this discussion with the intention of it being open simultaneously with whichever SCANfile# workbook I may have open at the time.

```
Sub Copy and Paste Data ()
'select cell on target workbook/worksheet
Range("X1").Select
'  
'select the data from the saved  workbook that the macro runs from
'
Columns("SCAMNmacro.xlsm C:G").Select
Selection.Copy
'
'Paste into SCANfile#.xlm.xml
'
Windows("SCANFILE01.xml").Activate
Range("X1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

This works fabulously as long as I run it from the SCANfile01.xml I had opened as I created it.  As soon as I open the Macro enabled workbook with a different scanfile, it errors out.

How do I set this up so that the Macro works on any ScanSheet?  I tried working with Thisworkbook and Activeworkbook to no avail.  I am not a programmer so most of this has been recorded with me tweaking inside the VBA editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Workbook variables for referencing the proper Workbooks:

```
Dim MacroSheet as Workbook
Set MacroSheet = ThisWorkbook

Dim ScanFile as Workbook
Set ScanFile = Workbooks.Open("PATH TO YOUR FILE")
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
MacroSheet.Columns("G").Copy
```